# Google Analytics: historical data does not but Real-Time data works

Tags: google-analytics

Our website has around 260,000 to 300,000 sessions each day. There had 4 days that the historical data is zero but Real-Time works correctly.

Here is a summary of what I know and have checked:

1. Real Time reporting is working.
2. GA reports no problems with tracking code, neither does tag manager.
3. We haven't changed any code and nothing has changed on the server apart from increased resources (CPU and RAM).
4. A subdomain on the same server with a different GA account is reporting fine, although this site has only a tiny fraction of the traffic on our main site.
5. I am not using a filtered view (and I have checked I am looking at today's date!).

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about question with Google Analytics website and is not programing related. Might want to try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also He is asking for today's date without considering [data processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983#DataProcessingLatency).